# Clickhouse: Select from Postgresql through ODBC

Tags: postgresql, subquery, odbc, clickhouse, sql-optimization

I have table (Postgresql):

```
CREATE TABLE odbc_table (
    a int4,
    b int4,
    ...
)
CREATE INDEX index1 (a, b)
```

and table (ClickHouse):

```
CREATE TABLE ch_table (
    k Int32,
    ...
)
```

In ClickHouse with ODBC executing a request:

```
SELECT * FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1 AND b in (SELECT k FROM ch_table WHERE ...)
```

As a result, a request is sent to Postgresql:

```
SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1
```

trying to get the whole table.

How to specify that part of the request is executed first:

```
SELECT k FROM ch_table WHERE ...
```

and a request of the form was sent to Postgresql:

```
SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1 and b in (1, 2, ...)
```

?

Comment: probably make sense introduce [External Dictionary](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-odbc) to store all required data on CH side?

Comment: will the where-clause ignored for *SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1*? Which version of CH used?

Comment: not sure that this help but try to use [enable_optimize_predicate_expression](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#enable-optimize-predicate-expression)-param: *SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1 and b in (...) SETTINGS enable_optimize_predicate_expression=1*

Comment: Sorry, request to Postgresql: SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1

Comment: Version ClickHouse: 20.1.6

Comment: Using SETTINGS enable_optimize_predicate_expression=1 didn't help

Comment: odbc_table - operating table on the PostgreSQL side. Using a External Dictionary is not appropriate

Comment: could you check: will be the where-clause ignored for *SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1* other words which sql-query be received on Postgress-side (containing *where* or not)?

Comment: Yes, it contains. Request: SELECT a, b FROM odbc_table WHERE a = 1. With SETTINGS enable_optimize_predicate_expression=1 and without.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218515/discussion-between-vladimir-and-ask125342).